# Using custom attribute jQuery selectors with dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have a series of cascading drop downs that are populated with a database. I'm trying to pull the data from a row in my database once the final item in the series is selected. I gave the row a custom attribute, but can't seem to get the data from it. Here is a simple example of what I want to accomplish.

http://jsfiddle.net/WsrBX/

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <form>
        <div>no id</div>
        <select>
            <option>pick</option>
            <option data-pick="33">with id</option>
        </select>
        <div id="there">has an id</div>
        <div>nope</div>
    </form>
</div>
    <div id="yup"></div><!--value should appear here upon selection-->
</body>
```

JS

```
    $('option[data-pick]').on('keyup change', function(){
    var idString = $(this).attr('option[data-pick]');
    $('#yup').text(idString);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form>
            <div>no id</div>
            <select id="sel">
                <option>pick</option>
                <option data-pick="33">with id</option>
            </select>
            <div id="there">has an id</div>
            <div>nope</div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="yup"></div>
    <!--value should appear here upon selection-->
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#sel').on('keyup change', function () {
    var idString = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-pick');
    $('#yup').text(idString);
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WsrBX/2/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/WsrBX/1/

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
var idString = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-pick');
$('#yup').text(idString);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Several tips:

1. The `change` event only happens on `<select>`, and you cannot capture it on `<option>`.
2. The `keyup` event literally means keys of the keyboard, which may not be what you want.

Proper solution should be listening for `change` on `<select>`, and find the corresponding `<option>` using `selectedIndex` of `<select>` DOM element. Example below:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var idString = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-pick');
    $('#yup').text(idString);
});
```

Comment: How would you prevent the empty div from displaying "null" with this approach?

Comment: Just make some test on the result: `if (idString) { $('#yup').text(idString); }`